# Find the variance of W when given $W = x + 2y + 3z$.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, covariance

1. x,y,z are random numbers given w = x + 2y + 3z.
   also given that the mean of x,y,z= 1,8,0 respectively.
   what is the mean of the random number w ?
2. Assuming the Standard deviation of the random numbers x,y,z = 1 
   and the numbers are uncorrelated, 
   what will the variance of the random number w ?
3. Assuming the Standard deviation of the random numbers x,y,z = 1 
   and the numbers are uncorrelated except of x,y that correlation of Rxy = 9
   what will the variance of the random number w ?

I dont know how to solve this problem, and how to approach it.

Can i get a full solution with explanation please ?

Thanks

Comment: The covariance of $W$ and what else? And are $X, Y, Z$ independent?

Comment: yes independent with no correlation between them

Comment: A **co**variance involves two random variables, here just $W$ is given, and we don't even know how $x,y,z$ are distributed.

Comment: Covariance involves **two** not necessarily distinct random variables, as in $\text{Cov}(U,V)$. You should state the independence, if independence is to be specified, in the problem. (Or uncorrelatedness, if that is what is specified in the original problem.)

Comment: I dont know if its helps but x,y,z,w are all random numbers(maybe is obvious). its a question from an exam doesnt tell much more than this.

Comment: Is this from an exercise you were asked to do? Then they might have asked for the covariance of $W$ and $X$, or something like that.  Please quote the question exactly.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem exactly as it was stated in the exam?

Comment: I'm doing it now

Comment: My guess is that they are asking about the **variance** of $W$.

Comment: you are right, that what happen when I'm copying/translating like a monkey :)

Comment: @SilverCrow: Unfortunately, because of difficulties that accompanied the translation process, the question is likely to be closed soon.   A correct version, together with an indication of what you have tried, might have led to answers useful to you and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all random variables $U,V$ and constants $a,b$:

Expectation is Linear : $$\mathsf E(aU+bV) ~=~ a\,\mathsf E(U)+b\,\mathsf E(V)$$

Variance is *not* linear, but we have the rule that : $$\mathsf {Var}(aU+bV) ~=~ a^2\,\mathsf {Var}(U)+b^2\,\mathsf {Var}(V)-2ab\,\mathsf {Cov}(U,V)$$

However, *when* $U,V$ are uncorrelated : $$\mathsf {Var}(aU+bV)~=~ a^2\,\mathsf {Var}(U)+b^2\,\mathsf {Var}(V)\color{silver}{\require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{-2ab\,\mathsf {Cov}(U,V)}}$$

The correlation cooefficient s $$R_{U,V} ~=~ \dfrac{\mathsf {Cov}(U,V)}{\sqrt{~\mathsf {Var}(U)~\mathsf{Var}(V)~}}$$

Use these rules.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks :)